# Room database: how I can get value after I insert it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

this is my on click function when user click on `SIGN UP` and I want to create `User & Cart` in my database database, the problem how I can get User ID after I Insert the user in my database because I have to get it to create a `Cart` to the `User`

```
clicked = !clicked
if (confirmpassword != password) {
    message = "Incorrect password! please try again"
} else if (inputChack(fullname, email, password)) {
    message = "Information is incomplete"
} else {
    user.email = email
    user.fullName = fullname
    user.password = password
    userVM.addUser(user)
    //cart.userID = userVM.user.value.userID [pass user ID]
    //cartVM.addCart(cart) [cartID (autoGenerate) , userID]
    Log.d("user & cart", "adding users & cart")
}
```

```
fun addUser(user: User) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        roomUserRepository.addUser(user)
    }
}
```

I try

```
fun addUser(user: User) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        roomUserRepository.addUser(user)
        checkUser(user.email)
    }
}

fun getUser(email: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val foundUser = roomUserRepository.getUser(email)
        if(foundUser != null){
             _user.value = foundUser
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the previously saved values it taken ​​then the value is updated

Cart Table

[cartID (autoGenerate) , userID]

[1 , 0 (default value)] it should be 1 `userID`

[2 , 1 (previous user id)] it should be 2 `userID`

[3 , 2 (previous user id)] it should be 3 `userID`

So when I click on `SIGN UP` first it add based on old value then it updated

UserDao

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_table")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var userID: Int = 0,
    var fullName: String = "Missing",
    var email: String = "Missing",
    var password: String = "Missing",
    var phone: Long = -1,
    var profileImage: String = "Missing",
    var userType: Int = -1,
) {

    constructor(
        userID: Int
    ) : this(
        userID,
        fullName = "Missing",
        email = "Missing",
        password = "Missing",
        phone = -1,
        profileImage = "Missing",
        userType = -1,
        )
}
```

Comment: Add code for the `User` entity and Dao. Also what is primary key for the `User`?

Comment: the primary is userID

Answer (score 2):

The `@Insert` function can return a Long (in a single insert) or a LongArray (for multiple inserts). IF userID is an ineteger type Int/Long (and some others such as Byte) and is annotated with `@PrimaryKey`, then this will be the value of the userID. Retrieve this value or rebuild the UI that displays the list (as this will then extract the userID).